# Saving a variable for all users viewing the website

Tags: javascript, html, variables, save, reload

I am working on incrementing a variable for a script for my site, but before moving on with that I got a question. if I have a variable which I increment by one whenever a function is called and I then save the variable, either by localstorage or by cookies, is it visible for all users on the website that the variable has been updated whenever they reload the page?

Comment: Only that user in that exact browser.

Comment: Cookies are specific to the user. If you want the same value to be visible to multiple users, you'll need to store it server-side.

Comment: You may want to read up on how the client side differs from the server side

Comment: yep as other commentors point out, to share state across users, you will need to deliver that state to each user when their browser requests your page. my preferred way is to set a data attribute on the body tag. in a server side ejs template, that would look like `<body data-counter="<%= myCounter %>">`; and in client side jquery you would access it like `JSON.parse($(body).data(counter))`

Comment: So if I wan't to store it server side, does that mean I just have to make the variable in a .php script and save it in that script, and then whenever I need to increment it, I just increment it in the .php script and then when I need to display it, I just pass the current value to the html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - cookies and local storage are client-specific.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the answer, could you please look at the question I left in the comments?